# How do i get a string inputted by user to be broken up character by character and put in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I wanted to allow the user to input a string and then break it piece by piece and put it into an array to process further.

```
int main () 
 {
 std::string str;
 std::cout<<"Enter the value: ";
 std::getline(std::cin, str);
 std::cout << std::endl << "Value is :" << str;
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: why do you want to do this? A `std::string` has already all you need to treat the string as an array of characters

Comment: @idclev463035818 how do i exactly do that ?

Comment: do what? `str[i]` is the i-th character

Comment: @RanjulRamachandran `std::string` is already container

Comment: `for (char c : str) { /* do something with c */ }`

Comment: @idclev463035818 i get you. but umm just asking how is this "std::cout<<"Enter value" , std::string str etc different from the normal string str; ,cout<<"Enter value".

Comment: @SanderDeDycker i think that would be the answer..i guess..mm

Comment: I dont understand what you mean. There is no difference to a "normal string". A "normal string" is an array of characters

Comment: please edit the question to include the code that you would like to write, but cannot because you think you need an array of characters

Comment: @idclev463035818 i wanted to convert the input entered into the string to an array and work with the individual characters,numbers,symbols involved in the input...hope im clear...

Comment: please edit the question to include the code that you would like to write, but cannot because you think you need an array of characters

Comment: What are the "pieces" you want to work on? Individual characters or whole words? Digits or numbers? `std::stringstream` might help.

Comment: @MSalters i wanted to work on the individual characters...will check on stringstream...thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job.
It initializes the vector `vec` with each character in the string.

```
std::vector<char> vec(str.begin(), str.end());
```